# Java Swing layout manager circular reference being set twice

Tags: java, swing, circular-reference

Can anybody explain why circular reference is being set twice in the followig code?

```
//declare panel
this.cntnrPnl = new JPanel();
//define layout manager for the panel - but why circ ref?
this.cntnrPnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.cntnrPnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Why is it necessary to link the `BoxLayout` back to the `JPanel` container explicitly instead of  `JPanel.setLayout` doing the setting itself behind the scene and using a setter from `BoxLayout` for code compactness?

E.g.:

```
this.cntnrPnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
//and then in JPanel.setLayout have something line
_layout.setContainer(this);
```

Comment: It seems your question is not why there are circular references but why the client code has to wire it up by passing the `Container` to `BoxLayout` constructor.

Comment: Good point.  Let me work on rephrasing

Comment: OK -- check it out now, hopefully clearer

Comment: Also consider extending `Box`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because BoxLayout is a special layout that needs a reference to the target container it lays out. That's not the case of all the layout managers. It would be ugly to add a specific case for BoxLayout in the `setLayout()` method. And it would also mean that the BoxLayout would be in an unstable state after its construction, since it wouldn't have the mandatory target container yet.

The reverse could have been done though: having the BoxLayout constructor call `setLayout(this)` on the target container. But I don't know why it hasn't been done.

Comment: `BoxLayout` constructor cannot call `setLayout` because there may be multiple `LayoutManagers` for the same `Container`, no?

Comment: I meant different layout managers at different times, essentially, call setLayout with different objects are differenr times

Comment: Yes, that could explain it. Or maybe they just wanted to be coherent with the other layout managers, which must be set on the container.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it necessary to link the `BoxLayout` back to the `JPanel` container explicitly instead of `JPanel.setLayout` doing the setting itself behind the scene and using a setter from `BoxLayout` for code compactness?

What you call `JPanel.setLayout` is actually [Container.setLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setLayout%28java.awt.LayoutManager%29):

```
public void setLayout(LayoutManager mgr)
```

You call call the method with a `BoxLayout` because it `implements LayoutManager`. But `LayoutManager` does not have a `setContainer` method, so it would not have worked without adding that method. But it seems that *most* layout managers don't care about a container so the method would not belong there.

Would it be possible for `BoxLayout` constructor to do the magic? Maybe not, though a `BoxLayout` is tied to a `Container`, the reverse is not necessarily true. Consider:

```
this.cntnrPnl = new JPanel();
BoxLayout bY = new BoxLayout(this.cntnrPnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
BoxLayout bX = new BoxLayout(this.cntnrPnl, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
```

Now at different times you can call `this.cntnrPnl.setLayout(bX)` and `this.cntnrPnl.setLayout(bY)`.

So looking at all options, it seems the current API is best, though of course all this is somewhat subjective.

By the way, please consider renaming `cntnrPnl` to `containerPanel`. You are not really saving much by stripping the vowels.

Answer (score 0):

Because a JPanel is not the only available container in Swing. In particular, you might create your own container class and not know about those special requirements for BoxLayout. As a result, the layout manater would not work for your implementation.

Now one could ask why the BoxLayout needs a reference to the JPanel to begin with, but this is a different matter.

Comment: do you mean that you could set the layout of the panel X to layout A, yet set container Y as the target of the layout ? i would think if you're setting panel X to have layout A as its layout, the target of layout A should ALWAYS be X and not some other container.

Comment: No, I meant that the API, which was defined at some point, declared a method `Container#setLayout` which did not have the implicit requirement that implementing container classes inject themselves in the layout. There is no contract for containers to invoke `LayoutManager#setContainer` (in fact, most LayoutManagers don't have that method to begin with).